# Parse 2 difference Soap Response PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, response

I'm new in php, how to parse 2 difference response from soap xml ?

Response 1

```html
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:MobileAgentAPI="urn:openApi">
<SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<MobileAgentAPI:invokeResponse>
 <SOAP-ENV:BodySOAP-ENV:Body>
  <values xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="MobileAgentAPI:SoapMapValue[13]">
 <item>
  <name>amount</name>
  <singleValue>5000</singleValue>
 </item>
 <item>
  <name>balance</name>
  <singleValue>12210000</singleValue>
 </item>
 <item>
  <name>lastBalance</name>
  <singleValue>12215000</singleValue>
 </item>
 <item>
  <name>returnCode</name>
  <singleValue>00</singleValue>
 </item>
 <item>
```

Response 2

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:MobileAgentAPI="urn:openApi"><SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><MobileAgentAPI:invokeResponse><invokeReturn><values xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="MobileAgentAPI:SoapMapValue[6]"><item><name>balance</name><singleValue>15420000</singleValue></item><item><name>returnCode</name><singleValue>01</singleValue></item><item><name>transactionStatus</name><singleValue>02</singleValue></item><item><name>errorCode</name><singleValue>324</singleValue></item><item><name>errorDescription</name><singleValue>(324) Maaf, transaksi pada 01/10/18 06:00 gagal. Nomor tujuan tidak terdaftar. =</singleValue></item><item><name>tran
```

im try with DOM Document but if we have 2 response the result is error

Comment: Please ask a question. What you're saying makes no sense. Complete your question or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you try to parse the XML response?
With the native PHP [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.soapclient.php) class, you handle at least PHP arrays or betterly objects.

Use a WSDL to PHP generator so you won't wonder how to construct the request data nor how to handle the response as you'll always use an OOP approach which is better. Try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project.

Comment: i want get response for my project sir, but idk how if i'm get 2 different response